# Zend Framework - Select query question

Tags: php, zend-framework, select

I have a query where i join a couple of tables. 2 tables contain the same fieldname, so i want to select 1 table AS another name. I know how to do that, but it seems that when i query a field AS another name, it selects only that field.

My question is: how can i select all fields in the table, and a particular field AS another name?

This is how i have my code at this moment:

```
    $select->from('one');
    $select->join('two', 'one.item_id = two.id', array('item_name' => 'name'));
    $select->join('three', 'one.item_id = three.item_id');
```

So i want to select all from two, and name the field name AS item_name.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should do it how it's supposed to be done: selecting EACH field you need. You're familiar with the subject "do not `select *`", I assume.

Comment: Well, have a *LOT* of fields and i have to select them all, so I was hoping for an easier way :( Can you explain why select * is bad practice? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this but I think you're able to do this:

```
$select->join('two', 'one.item_id = two.id', array('item_name' => 'name', '*'));
```

Comment: I see you edited my answer, that's fine, but both notations (`'name as item_name'` or `'item_name' => 'name'`) will work, in case someone is interested :-).